# Typeahead not showing suggestion list

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, typeahead.js

I have been working in a Spring MVC application and trying to use Twitter Typeahead to show suggestions. The problem however is that although the suggestions are fetched from the server correctly but the suggestion box is not showing up at all. The same code had worked previously but is not working now.

**my javascript code is:**

```
var skillSuggestions=new Bloodhound({
        datumTokenizer:Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('value'),
        queryTokenizer:Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,

        remote:{
            url:"/tags/get.html/?searchTerm=%QUERY",
            filter:function(x){
                return $.map(x,function(item){
                    return{value:item.name};
                });
            },
            wildcard:'%QUERY',

        }
    });

    skillSuggestions.initialize();

    $('#skill-name').typeahead({
        hint:true,
        highlight:true,
        minLength:1
    },{
        name:'value',
        displayKey:'value',
        source:skillSuggestions.ttAdapter()
    })
```

and for the input 'j' the received json response is:

```
[{"id":"56d546f5535a3c819f080558","name":"Java","category":"Information Technology","subCategory":"Programming/Software","createdDate":1456817909648,"updatedDate":null,"createdBy":"bob","modifiedBy":null},{"id":"56d93f8e535a773c1f8cc846","name":"Javascript","category":"Information Technology","subCategory":"Programming / Software","createdDate":1457078158043,"updatedDate":null,"createdBy":"bob","modifiedBy":null},{"id":"56d93fa2535a773c1f8cc847","name":"JQuery","category":"Information Technology","subCategory":"Programming / Software","createdDate":1457078178030,"updatedDate":null,"createdBy":"bob","modifiedBy":null},{"id":"56d93fb7535a773c1f8cc848","name":"JavaSE","category":"Information Technology","subCategory":"Programming / Software","createdDate":1457078199012,"updatedDate":null,"createdBy":"bob","modifiedBy":null},{"id":"56e226a47b49d4215eaefa9a","name":"javahhhh","category":"hhhhh","subCategory":"jjjjjj","createdDate":1457661604324,"updatedDate":null,"createdBy":null,"modifiedBy":null}]
```

I want to display the field `name` in the suggestions. Am I missing something? Please help. I looked at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21530063/how-do-we-set-remote-in-typeahead-js),[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21710289/how-to-use-typeahead-js-0-10-step-by-step-remote-prefetch-local),[here](http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/) and many more but couldn't get what went wrong.

Comment: what does this do?? `source:skillSuggestions.ttAdapter()`

Comment: I think that links **Typeahead** and **Bloodhound**. The documentation is not clear

Comment: the source is the actual point where it shows you the data when you are typing. I guess this is twitter bootstrap type ahead. check if its this one https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/ . if so then you must implement the `substringMatcher ` function to return you the data to be shown as you type along

Comment: @Reddy not exactly.  The substringMatcher is intended to be a demo for using a local typeahead datasource.

Comment: @AbhisekLamsal can you put a console.log statement in your filter function and verify what is happening in there? `filter:function(x){
                return $.map(x,function(item){
console.log(item.name);
                    return{value:item.name};
                });
            }`

Comment: but the `Bloodhound` example is different from what you have. Never used Bloodhound personally so my thoughts on this would be minimal

Comment: In this case, the code looks correct.  My issues with this have centered on how the filter and map results were not what I expected.

Comment: @Reddy previously the solution worked even with the ttAdapter part. I tried your solution, it shows undefined on the suggestion list

Comment: If you get undefined you are very close to solving it... What I can guess is.. You get the count of search results right but it shows undefined text in it.. Right??

Comment: @Reddy nope. In fact the input of first character returns 2 suggestions and that of 2 or 3 returns more than that

Comment: @whipdancer I prented out what you have said and it shows me an array of json Objects and I thinks it is working properly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is with your datum tokenizer. You're tokenizing in the key `value` in the response objects, but that key doesn't exist in your response. The `obj.whitespace` tokenizer accepts a list of object keys to tokenize.

Change this:

```
datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace("Value"),
```

to this (for example):

```
datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace("name", "category"),
```

When you change the tokenizer, it's also necessary to change what's displayed as suggestions and in the selected option. You attempt to do that with this line in the typeahead options:

```
displayKey:'value',
```

... but again, you're referencing an object key (`value`) that doesn't exist. You want the key `name`.

```
display: 'name', // This is the object key you wish displayed
```

Comment: exactly what i needed after a solid 45 minutes of searching.

Answer (score 0):

I'll show you how I solved it in our implementation.  We use an `identify` function as well as a `filter` function on the data.

In this case, the data being returned via the web service has an `id` property and a `name` property.  Those get mapped to the object used for populating the actual typeahead suggestions.

```
taSource = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace("Value"),
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    identify: function (obj) { return obj.Value; },
    remote: {
        url: "/service/url",
        filter: function (data) {
            if (data) {
                return $.map(data, function (object) {
                    return { Id: object.id, Value: object.name };
                });
            } else {
                return {};
            }
        },
        rateLimitBy: 'debounce',
        rateLimitWait: 400
    }
});
```

Notice that I map back an Id property and a Value property.  Check your case for your property names.